# How to pre-fill an Outlook e-mail from an HTML form with only values?

Tags: html, forms, email, outlook, submit

I made a form for sending an e-mail to my address by the user by creating an email filled with the form data. The problem is that after pressing the send button, I only want the values to appear filled in the email, and not the keys. Is there a possible way to do that?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="MAILTO:someone@somethig.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name" value="your name"><br>
E-mail:<br>
<input type="text" name="mail" value="your email"><br>
Comment:<br>
<input type="text" name="comment" value="your comment" size="50"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When submitting the form, it opens outlook new email with this filled in:

> name=your name
>   mail=your email
>   comment=your comment

But I want it to look like this:

> your name
>   your email
>   your comment

Comment: are you trying to hide the labels `Name:<br>` or are you trying to hide the inputs `<input type="text" name="name" value="your name"><br>`?

Comment: @Jeff Puckett II After I press the submit button, I have the name="Thing you put there" IN the already filled email, which I don't want

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get rid of the `=`, but you can name all the inputs `" "` to kinda remove the key:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="MAILTO:someone@somethig.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
Name:<br>
<input type="text" name=" " value="your name"><br>
E-mail:<br>
<input type="text" name=" " value="your email"><br>
Comment:<br>
<input type="text" name=" " value="your comment" size="50"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This results in the following output in the pre-filled email:

> =your name
>    =your email
>    =your comment

Answer (score 0):

Building on my other answer, you could concat all values into one hidden value, and then use the `=` as a natural separator:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="MAILTO:someone@somethig.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain" onsubmit="concat_form_values()">
Name:<br>
<input id="name" type="text" value="your name"><br>
E-mail:<br>
<input id="email" type="text" value="your email"><br>
Comment:<br>
<input id="comment" type="text" value="your comment" size="50"><br><br>

<input id="aggregate" type="hidden" name=" ">

<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
</body>

<script>
  function concat_form_values(){
    document.getElementById("aggregate").value = '============================\n' +
      document.getElementById("name").value + '\n' +
      document.getElementById("email").value + '\n' +
      document.getElementById("comment").value
  }
</script>

</html>
```

which would result in an email opened pre-filled with this content:

> =============================
>   your name
>   your email
>   your comment